# Flutter DataColumn width

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to size the datacolumn width which match the content, for example in the image below, the Quantity column is too wide and I'd like to narrow it down.

```
  DataTable(
      columns: [
        DataColumn(
            label: Text("Quantity"),
            numeric: false,
        DataColumn(
            label: Text("Product"),
            numeric: false,
      ],
      rows: positions
          .map((position) => DataRow(
                  onSelectChanged: (b) {
                    onSelectedRow(b, position);
                  },
                  cells: [
                    DataCell(
                      Text("${position.amount}"),
                    ),
                    DataCell(
                      Text(position.product),
                      onTap: () {
                        util.toast(position.product);
                      },
                    ),
                  ]))
          .toList(),
    );
```

[image]